# How can I post some of the pages from google books preview?

Tags: support

I heard someone cannot view the page that I can view in Google books,
But sometimes I may have problems inside the book, how can I paste the image or page from Google books to this website?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree that ASCII text from a book is superior to an image of text from a book, but how to get there..

I had *very* good results pasting in a Google Books image into http://www.newocr.com/ to produce a summary, as you can see here:

[Non-unital rings: a few examples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37705/non-unital-rings-a-few-examples/37716#37716)

Of course Fair Use is still absolutely in play, so obviously we only support this for **brief excerpts** that are relevant to the question.

Answer (score 10):

Different people have different opinions about this. Personally, I do not like to see images of book pages. I strongly prefer questions and answers where the relevant passages are retyped and reworded.

I don't see any reason not to retype the question in our own words, add your motivation in asking it, say what you have tried so far, and summarize any non-standard definitions. That makes a question that I want to answer and it lets me focus my response on the actual issues the asker describes in the question. When I see an image of a book page, I don't know what the asker has tried or what aspect of the question they are stuck on.

Comment: I totally agree with your opinion Carl. And may I add, I think that in most cases the true reasons for posting questions just using images from a book or with a link to google books and saying something like "Solve problem X in page Y" or "Explain concept X in page Y" is nothing more than laziness and a lack of effort on the part of the person asking the question.

Comment: I say this because I looked at the OP's profile and saw some questions that were downvoted and even closed because they were asked in a poor way. And it seems from the comments that the OP has been politely encouraged to improve the quality of his posts by different users. So I see this question as a reason to try to avoid making the questions self contained. Of course it is easier to just give a link to a book than actually taking the time to write everything down using some markdown, but that's not very well received from the majority of users of the site I guess.

Comment: @Adrián: For related analysis, see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1805/6179

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but I understood the OP's question in this way: How can I download the image from the google books preview, so that I can put it into my post. (I am not saying that this should be encouraged in general, but in some situations it might be useful and some people might not know how to use it.)

First thing is to get to the page you want, it might be good to zoom in to get better resolution. What do you do next depends on your browser:

**Mozilla Firefox:** Tools -> Page info -> Media
Then find the picture you want and click on "Save As".

**Internet Explorer** I guess there is better way to do this. But the only one I know is this one: I display page (or several pages) in the browser (with sufficient zoom). Then I go into the folder "Temporary Internet Files". (The location of this folder is system-dependent, for me it's "C:\Users\martin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Low\Content.IE5\".) I search for book*.png;book*.jpg (or *.png;*.jpg) and order them either by date or by size. (I prefer size to get the files with better zoom first.) Then it should be relatively easy to find your file.

It might be useful to delete the whole content of "Temporary Internet Files" before doing this. (So that you do not have so many files to look in.)

Comment: On Firefox, I used to use the [ScrapBook](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/scrapbook/) extension to grab pages from Google Books...

Comment: What happened to good-ol' screencap?