# Mathpix Snip Tool: Automatic $\rm\LaTeX$ code generation from typed or handwritten math!

Tags: discussion, mathjax, images

The [Mathpix Snip](https://mathpix.com/) tool is quite impressive. I recommend you check it out! It could save you a lot of effort in trying to write $\rm\LaTeX$ code.

Here is an example at work. Original image:

[image]

First crack at the $\rm\LaTeX$ code generated by Mathpix Snip:

```
\(\begin{aligned} P(Y>1.5 | Y>1) &=\frac{P(Y>1.5 \cap Y>1)}{P(Y>1)} \\ &=\frac{P(Y>1.5)}{P(Y>1)} \\ &=\frac{1-P(Y \leq 1.5))}{1-P(Y \leq 1)} \\ &=\frac{1-F(1.5)}{1-F(1.5)} \\ &=\frac{0.125}{0.5} \\ &=0.25 \end{aligned}\)
```

which displays as

(\begin{aligned} P(Y>1.5 | Y>1) &=\frac{P(Y>1.5 \cap Y>1)}{P(Y>1)} \\ &=\frac{P(Y>1.5)}{P(Y>1)} \\ &=\frac{1-P(Y \leq 1.5))}{1-P(Y \leq 1)} \\ &=\frac{1-F(1.5)}{1-F(1.5)} \\ &=\frac{0.125}{0.5} \\ &=0.25 \end{aligned})

So the only catch here is that MathJax doesn't behave quite the same as regular $\rm\LaTeX$ in, say, TeXstudio. That is a setting you can change, though.

Comment: Detexify probably my way or TeX stackexchange search.

Comment: Does detexify do whole equations? Even multiline? The Mathpix Snip does.

Comment: No, but if I want code that works, I test in in VerbTeX, or I make it myself as there's about 20 ways to do the same thing.

Comment: I have added ([meta-tag:mathjax]) tag - which seems like a reasonable tag for this question. Perhaps also ([meta-tag:images]) would be suitable? (As I wasn't entirely sure, I'll leave the decision whether to add this tag to others.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Agree with images tag. Edited.

Comment: I don't see a question in this "question". And maybe it's just me, but I don't see what it has to do with math.stackexchange.

Comment: Related: [Extraction of Math -expressions with OCR from scanned photos?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3731)

Comment: @GerryMyerson In my opinion, it is a bit related to [math.se] in this sense: Some users post their questions (on answers) as images. Often other users retype their questions. If there are tools which can make it easier to convert something from image to text (be it regular text or - in this case - formulas), they might be useful.

Comment: @Martin, thanks. I'd encourage OP to edit something like what Martin has written into the body of the question (preferably before it gets closed as off-topic).

Comment: For the record, I voted to close this question.  I wouldn't vote to delete it, because it contains useful information that should be retained in some form.  Still, as there is no question there is no sense in having people be able to answer it.

Comment: And I don't really care if it is closed. It's more of an announcement them anything else, but the SE format isn't well-suited to that sort of thing.

Comment: The link in this post went from one with a referral code to a link to the image in the post. Can you post a neutral link so there is no concern about using meta to get some referral benefit?

Comment: In another discussion related to topic of images in MSE posts, Jeff Atwood gave a recommendation of a tool which could be used for getting *text* from a picture: [How can I post some of the pages from google books preview?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2600#2603) (Of course, that's completely different from getting math formulas.)

Comment: I will mention this recent question: [What tools can be used to extract MathJax/LaTeX from scanned input?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31182) (Since this one was closed, I have posted something which is closer to question than to an announcement.)