# What tools can be used to extract MathJax/LaTeX from scanned input?

Tags: discussion, mathjax, images

Some users post question (and sometimes also answers) which contain text and formulas as images. Often some other users help with retyping the questions into properly formatted text and MathJax formula. For short text, typing the formula is probably the fastest way, but still it might be useful to know: Are there some tools that can be used to get MathJax/LaTeX from a scanned formulas? (Or even mix of text and formulas.)

To make this question more focused, let us concentrate here only on input which contains formulas. (Be it handwritten text or typed text.) Scanning plain text would be a question for a separate discussion.

I have posted this questions partially as a follow-up to previous question: [Mathpix Snip Tool: Automatic $\rm\LaTeX$ code generation from typed or handwritten math!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31106) It was closed and some of the objections in the comments were that it wasn't really formulated as a question - more as an announcement. I hope this one is closer to a question. (There is also an older related question: [Extraction of Math -expressions with OCR from scanned photos?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3731) My guess would be that situation might have changed a bit since 2012 and it is likely that more tools of this kind are now available.)

I will certainly admit that this question is not exactly about the intended topic of Mathematics Meta. On the other hand, since it might be useful for users of this site, perhaps it might be useful to have here at least some pointers to places where information about this topic is available. (And I think that answers describing some specific solution with details included by a user who has experience with that particular tool might be useful, too.)

Comment: I will also mention this answer by Jeff Atwood: [How can I post some of the pages from google books preview?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2600#2603) He recommended there https://www.newocr.com/ - however, this seems to be page for scanning text, no mathematical formulas.

Comment: who do you consider a tool ...

Comment: Thanks for posting, Martin!

Answer (score 16):

Let us create here a [community wiki](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/community-wiki/info) answer to collect resources on this topic elsewhere on the web.

Related posts on TeX Stack Exchange:

- [What is the status of generating LaTeX from handwriting (i.e., OCR)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1443) (August 2010)
- [How to convert PDF to (La)TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8503) (January 2011)
- [Image equation to TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/116863) (May 2013)
- [Possible to Convert Math in Picture into LaTeX? How?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155166) (January 2014)
- [Tool for converting maths writing to LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/197218) (August 2014)

Comment: I've added in another TeX.SE question, as well as adding in the dates (technology moves fast!).